# If file exists with that name, what would RenameFile do? Will it delete the old file?

Tags: c#, file

I have this line of code in c#:

```
ftp.RenameFile(file_name, "folder_name/" + file_name);
```

where ftp is an instance of the FtpConnection class.

I'm interested to know what would happen if folder_name already has a file named file_name.
Would it delete the old file and replace it with the new one?

Comment: Why don't you try? Is it **that difficult**?

Comment: your action will be the answer to your question. somehow if it does some error thats the point you needed to ask whats that error and why it happened..

Comment: @zerkms I can't try, he ftp service isn't mine.

Comment: @petko_stankoski: and there are no publicly available FTP in the whole internet? I don't even mention you can install one easily in a minute.

Comment: What is the `FtpConnection` class? Where did it come from? What library is it a part of? Have you checked the documentation for the `RenameFile` function? What does it say? There are lots of possible behaviors, from replacement, to failure, to renaming, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't do anything. It doesn't delete the old file.

Answer (score 0):

Since  the [documentation](http://www.enterprisedt.com/products/edtftpnetpro/doc/manual/api/html/M_EnterpriseDT_Net_Ftp_FTPConnection_RenameFile.htm) (assuming I've got the right product <sup>(a)</sup>) doesn't seem to state one way or the other, the best thing you can do is try it out.

It should be immediately obvious what happens, though you probably want to try some different combinations to check effects of permissions and so forth.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> If I *don't* have the right product, the method still stands: either consult the documentation, or try it yourself.

Comment: Downvoter, if you tell me _why_ you think this is unhelpful, I'll gladly fix it.